# TinyMCE in Embedded IE not receiving enter keypresses

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce

Apologies if this question is a bit obscure, I've been banging my head against it for a while and I'm running out of ideas, so I hoped someone here might be able to help.

I'm attempting to use TinyMCE inside of an embedded instance of IE. Weirdly, it's not processing enter/return keypresses. The return keypresses are definitely being received, if I do this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'Hello World!');
       }
      });
     },
...
```

then "Hello World!" gets inserted wherever my cursor is. I guess a reasonable thing would be to replace the `execCommand` by a call to whatever code TinyMCE executes on enter keypresses. Does anyone know what that function is, and if it's accessible? If not, does anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks,

Dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was because the window that the embedded IE was in was swallowing the keypresses.

Comment: Are you able to specify what you did change?
I have the same problem with the embedded IE webcontrol in my application. 

The return/enter key works fine in an standard html text ctrl. But not in tinyMCE.

Comment: I couldn't change anything - because I didn't control the application which was embedding IE. In short - I gave up.